# What is this plant with hairy stems and opposite leaves?

Tags: identification

Can someone tell me the name of this plant. It is growing in a pot in Morocco. It has hairy stem and leaves. I haven't seen any flowers yet, but I've been told they are blue or purple. It does not have a scent.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the group!  Can you add some more information to your question such as where you live and the temperature in your area.  Some additional pictures from the side would be helpful as well

Comment: And smell... I suspect this plant might have an aromatic scent? Is the stem more round or somewhat square?

Comment: thank you for replying ,no this plant have no scent ,the leaves are fuzzy as well as the stems ,and it looks like a small bush ,i was told it produce blue or purple flowers ,so waiting , and i live in morocco , guess this plant like sun coz it's has hair on leaves as most drought tolerant plants ,

Comment: Hi! Is that in a pot? It looks like it to me but I'm not sure. Also, what else is growing with it? Thanks!

Comment: yes growing in amedium size pot with Glandularia bipinnatifida and scented pelargonium and Moses in the Cradle , i ll make sure they d'ont overcrowd each other

Comment: Gees, I thought I could smell Lemon Sage...good question Stephie.

Comment: I agree that this looks like a sage. Can you please crush a leaf and let us know if it then has any scent?

Comment: ain't sage i love the smell of sage so i know the difference

Comment: If you can get it to flower, one of us will nail the ID.

Comment: Are the leaves unpleasant to touch, slightly bristly?

Comment: My first thought was Tibouchina but this has less  striated veination. Hmm. Keep us posted. Curious about this one.

Comment: yes was told it could be tibouchina but the pattern on the leaves aren't the same , hopefully it will start to flower in the future ,would give me an idea ,i ll be posting the flowers , thx  Brenn

Comment: I too would vote of tibouchina, but wonder if it might not be a different species that the garden variety one we are all used to.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ocimum Tenuiflorum (Holy Basil).  More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocimum_tenuiflorum)

Comment: If it's holy basil, you can crush a small piece of leaf under your nose to check if it has a unique wonderful scent (as holy basil has).

Comment: It looks like  that to me too. I will post a photo of the leaves from our plant tomorrow.